# Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException - when resolving components with Resolve<T>

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

I'm having trouble manually resolving objects from my container. It seems that Windsor is not finding the suitable components even though the registration of the components goes through without problems. Specific to my case is that some components resolve fine, and others throw an exception. Notable is that constructor dependency injection works, even with dependencies I could not resolve manually.

This gets thrown when run:

> Castle.MicroKernel.ComponentNotFoundException
>     HResult=0x80131500
>     Message=No component for supporting the service Finance.Events.EventConductor.LoginConductor was found
>     Source=Castle.Windsor
>     StackTrace:
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Castle.MicroKernel.IKernelInternal.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments, IReleasePolicy policy, Boolean ignoreParentContext)
>      at Castle.MicroKernel.DefaultKernel.Resolve(Type service, IDictionary arguments)
>      at Castle.Windsor.WindsorContainer.ResolveT
>      at Finance.Framework.Bootstrapper.OnStartup(Object sender, StartupEventArgs e) in C:\Users\User\source\repos\Project\Project\Framework\Bootstrapper.cs:line 39
>      at System.Windows.Application.OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
>      at System.Windows.Application.<.ctor>b__1_0(Object unused)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
>      at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)

The Code:

```
protected override void Configure()
{
    _windowManager = new WindowManager();
    _container = new WindsorContainer();
    _container.AddFacility<TypedFactoryFacility>();

    _container.Install(new ShellInstaller(),
                       new FrameworkInstaller(),
                       new ViewModelInstaller(),
                       new ModelInstaller(),
                       new FactoryInstaller(),
                       new RepositoryInstaller(),
                       new NHibernateInstaller());
}
```

Each installer registers components one by one like this:

```
public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
{
        container.Register(Component.For<IEventAggregator>().ImplementedBy<EventAggregator>().LifestyleSingleton());
        container.Register(Component.For<ILoginConductor>().ImplementedBy<LoginConductor>().LifestyleTransient());
        container.Register(Component.For<IWindowManager>().ImplementedBy<WindowManager>().LifestyleSingleton());
        container.Register(Component.For<ILoginService>().ImplementedBy<MockLoginService>().LifestyleSingleton());
}
```

I'm trying to resolve my Object like this. Note that passing the LoginViewModel
to the windowManager works while the line before throws an exception.

```
protected override void OnStartup(object sender, StartupEventArgs e)
{
    _loginConductor = _container.Resolve<LoginConductor>(); // this throws the exception.
    _windowManager.ShowWindow(_container.Resolve<LoginViewModel>()); // this does not.
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Two bits of information would help answering that:
How `LoginConductor` is registered.
How (and when) it's being resolved.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback, i updated my question accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seeing the error because you're trying to resolve a *service* for `LoginConductor` but you don't register a *service* for `LoginConductor`.

You are registering a *component* for *service* `ILoginConductor` implemented by `LoginConductor`.

If the above sounds confusing, and the italicised words aren't clear, [there's a good primer in the documentation about it](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/services-and-components.md).

With that out of the way, the solution will be to align the *service* you resolve with the *service* of your *dependency*. Whether you keep `ILoginConductor` as the service or make the `LoginConductor` your service depends on your specific context.

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you've already resolved your issue - however, if it helps others:

Changing the `_loginConductor` part of your `OnStartup` method to read `_loginConductor = _container.Resolve<ILoginConductor>();` (note the interface use) should work, given that `ILoginConductor` is what's being registered as a Service. Worked for me when I had a similar issue.