# How to resolve Windsor container dependencies for a class library in ASP.NET Core Web API project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-webapi, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor

I have a ASP.NET Core Web API, whose `Program.cs` looks like below,

```
using Castle.Windsor;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// Add services to the container.

builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
var app = builder.Build();

var container = new WindsorContainer();

container.Install(new MyInstaller());

var adapter = container.Resolve<IMyApiAdapter>();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();
```

I am referencing my class library project in ASP.NET Core Web API,
My Installer class from the class library looks like this,

```
    public class MyInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
    {
        public void Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
        {
            container.Register(Component.For<IDbConnectionFactory>()
                .ImplementedBy<SqlDbConnectionFactory>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("connectionString", container.Resolve<IBaseDAL>().ConnectionString))
                .LifestyleSingleton());

            container.Register(Component.For<IClientResponseAdapter>()
                .ImplementedBy<ClientResponseAdapter>().LifestyleTransient());

            container.Register(Component.For<IMyApiAdapter>()
                .ImplementedBy<MyApiAdapter>()
                .DependsOn(Dependency.OnValue("container", container))
                .LifestyleTransient());
        }
    }
```

Once I run my Web API, I get the below error,

[image]

How to resolve this error?

And once resolved, I need to use `MyApiAdapter` class methods in the Controller.
How should I reference my dependencies in the Controller class?

Controller class

```
[ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {


private IMyApiAdapter _adapter;


        [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
        public string GetAsync()
        {
            HelperResponse hr = new HelperResponse();
            hr = _adapter.SetFormActiveFlag(100, true, "","");
            return hr.ResponseXml;
        }
}
```

**UPDATE after implementing the answer:**

Do I need to do something separately to install `IMyApiAdapter` related dependencies?

In the old implementation, I see in the constructor it is being resolved.

```
public class MyHandler: BaseHandler
    {
        #region Private Members
        private IDynamicFormsApiAdapter _adapter;

        #endregion Private Members

        #region Constructors
        public MyHandler()
        {
            _adapter = WebApplicationBase.Container.Resolve<IMyApiAdapter>();
        }
        #endregion Constructors
}
```

And WebApplicationBase.cs looks like this,

```
public class WebApplicationBase : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        protected static IIocContainer _iocContainer = new IocContainer();

        protected virtual void SetupWindsorContainer(params Castle.MicroKernel.Registration.IWindsorInstaller[] installers)
        {
            _iocContainer.RegisterInstaller(installers);
        }

        public static IWindsorContainer Container
        {
            get
            {
                return _iocContainer.Container;
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: [Does this answer help you ?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53067339/7687666)

Comment: ASP.NET Core Web API-related code guidance is missing from that answer. I am looking for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error you experiencing is due to the fact that there is no `IBaseDAL` implementation registered in the container when you are registering the `IDbConnectionFactory`. You should register the `IBaseDAL` implementation before your connection factory.

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IBaseDAL>().ImplementedBy<YourDALImpl>());
```

If your `IBaseDAL` isn't registered until later (some other Windsor installer) then you can use `DynamicParameters` to provide that dependency and it will be resolved when the factory is instantiated.

```cs
container.Register(Component.For<IDbConnectionFactory>()
    .ImplementedBy<SqlDbConnectionFactory>()
    .LifestyleSingleton()
    .DynamicParameters((k, d) => d["connectionString"] = k.Resolve<IBaseDAL>().ConnectionString));
```

Now that the error is resolved we can address how to get that dependency into your controllers.

The first thing you want to do is integrate the `IWindsorContainer` as the `IServiceProvider` for your Web API project. This needs to be done before you build the `WebApplication`.

```cs
//...
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();

// Add services via windsor
var container = new WindsorContainer();
builder.Host.UseWindsorContainerServiceProvider(container);
container.Install(new MyInstaller());

var app = builder.Build();
//...
```

`UseWindsorContainerServiceProvider` is an extension method provided from the NuGet package `Castle.Windsor.Extensions.DependencyInjection`.

Since the `IWindsorContainer` is now our service provider, anything registered to it can be injected into controllers either through "constructor injection" or through "method injection".

Constructor injection uses the constructor to acquire dependencies. Your weather controller would look like this:

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("[controller]")]
public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IMyApiAdapter _adapter;

    public WeatherForecastController(IMyApiAdapter adapter)
    {
        _adapter = adapter;
    }

    [HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
    public string GetAsync()
    {
        HelperResponse hr = new HelperResponse();
        hr = _adapter.SetFormActiveFlag(100, true, "", "");
        return hr.ResponseXml;
    }
}
```

You can also request dependencies on the controller action methods using the `FromServices` attribute:

```cs
[HttpGet(Name = "GetWeatherForecast")]
public string GetAsync([FromServices] IMyApiAdapter adapter)
{
    HelperResponse hr = new HelperResponse();
    hr = adapter.SetFormActiveFlag(100, true, "", "");
    return hr.ResponseXml;
}
```

You can read all about DI into ASP .NET Core controllers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/dependency-injection?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

Comment: So far great help :-) The controller code worked fine but using Swagger API got the following output. Posting the snip and error message in the edited question.

Comment: It's the same problem as before. You need all the different services to be registered in the Windsor container so they can be injected into your classes. Read the error stack trace and you can see all the missing services. All the ones with red lines seem to not be registered.

Comment: But, my `container.Install(new MyInstaller());` line takes care of that, in that Install method there is this line    `container.Register(Component.For<IDynamicFormsApiContext>()
                .ImplementedBy<DynamicFormsApiContext>()
                .LifestyleTransient());` Am I missing something?

Comment: Am I suppose to register these dependencies twice?

Comment: No, look at the error trace. It is telling you **exactly** what is happening. The error log is **very** good. `DynamicFormsApiAdapter` can't be created because its dependencies can't be injected (look at the constructor). It needs an `IFormattingUtilty` from first glance. It's hard to tell what else is wrong since I just see the error log and not the code. Windsor has to satisfy the full graph of dependencies to create that one object. Read up on some articles on Dependency Injection and how it works, specifically Constructor Injection.

Comment: I could get everything resolved, only the connectionString part is remaining. At runtime, it is throwing an error that connectionString is NULL, adding the image in question. How should I read that connection string from AppSettings file and pass it to the dependency? Actually it is happening in the Install method only so not sure how to resolve that one.

Comment: Able to resolve everything, I am using ASP.NET Core 6.0, and my DI class library is using .net framework 4.8 class library. So got an error related to `System.Web.HttpContext` updating in the question.

Comment: You could post a new question for that! The scope has really grown more than what SO likes to allow. One question. One answer.